# Identifying tense — present simple?

Tags: tense, present-simple

I have already asked this question from some teachers and student, some say these are present simples but in present simple we use "do/does" and etc. I want to know which type of sentences these are.

1. > what is your name.
2. > who are you.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but those would be interrogative sentences, and should properly have a question mark after them, since they are asking a question. Putting a period at the end makes it look more like an imperative -- a demand that you answer the question ("You will tell me your name.") -- but I would still say they are interrogative.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auxiliaries_and_contractions. Make sure that you understand at least *do, have*, and *be*.

Comment: We reverse the standard *subject + verb* order in interrogatives starting with *which, what, when, where, why,* etc. But we use the standard order if rephrased to, say *Your name is what?, You are who?* (though these aren't particularly common forms).

Comment: I think you are mistaken in thinking that in present simple we use *to do*.  When asking *who, what, where, when, why, how*, particularly when we're just asking about the existence or the nature of something, we just use *to be*, as in your examples.  In *"What is it?"*, we're just asking about the nature of "it".  In *What do you see?"* we're asking what is the object of your action of seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Questions employ *do/does* only if there is no other auxiliary verb present to invert with the subject. This is called "do support":

> I finished yesterday. → **Did** you finish yesterday? —*There is no auxiliary here, so* finish *requires "do support" to provide an auxiliary that can invert with the subject in a question.*
>
> I have finished. → **Have** you finished? — ***have*** here is an auxiliary, so it can invert with the subject in a question.
>
> I have a new car. → **Do** you have a new car? — ***have*** here is not an auxiliary but a lexical verb, so it requires "do support" in a question.

Sentences with a form of *BE*, however, work a little differently. *BE* is always treated as an auxiliary, even when it is the only verb:

> I am finishing the project today. → **Are** you finishing the project today? *AND*
>   I am finished. → **Are** you finished?

Note, by the way, that for some speakers *HAVE* can also be treated as an auxiliary when it is the only verb.

> I have a new car. → **Have** you a new car?

This was once very common, but it is slowly disappearing; it has an old-fashioned ring now.